# How to make a ruled book like UI for a Multiline Edit Text in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

So basically am building an app where in a edit text box which is a multi line one has to have an UI like a ruled notebook basically ruled lines would be there and the user can enter text on those lines how can I acheieve this using  ?
Or is there any different approach to this?